# One producer. Two consumers. Почему падает в runtime?

Tags: многопоточность, c++11

Я новичок в многопоточности. Не понимаю - почему не работает код ниже. Очевидно, что проблема в кривизне моего кода, но не вижу где именно.

Пытаюсь реализовать следующий алгоритм. Генератор (one producer) формирует очередь и по завершению работы выставляет флаг complete = true. Два кодера (two consumers) параллельно с генератором берут элемент из головы очереди. Как только очередь генератора становится пустой и окончательно сформированной (complete=true) - кодер увеличивает счетчик завершенных потоков на 1. При достижении счетчиком значения 2 обе очереди (очередь-приемник и закодированная очередь) удаляются.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>

template <typename T> class AbstractQueue {
public:
    virtual void push(T data) = 0;
    virtual T pop() = 0;
    virtual bool isEmpty() = 0;
    virtual void setComplete() = 0;
    virtual bool isComplete() = 0;
    virtual ~AbstractQueue(){}

    virtual void incCountThread() = 0;
    virtual int getCountThread() = 0;

};

template <typename T> class Queue : public AbstractQueue<T> {
protected:
    class Item {
    public:
        Item *prev, *next;
        T data;

        Item() : prev(nullptr), next(nullptr) {}

        ~Item() {
            prev = nullptr;
            next = nullptr;
        }
    };

    Item *first, *last;
    std::mutex mutex;
    std::mutex mutex2;
    std::mutex mutex3;
    bool complete;
    int count_thread;

public:
    Queue() : first(nullptr), last(nullptr), complete(false), count_thread(0) {}

    ~Queue() {
        Item *item = first, *next;

        while (item != nullptr) {
            next = item->next;
            delete item;
            item = next;
        }
        last  = nullptr;
        std::cout<< "Delete by id " << std::this_thread::get_id() << "\n";
    }

    void incCountThread() {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(mutex3);
        ++count_thread;
    }

    int getCountThread() {
        return count_thread;
    }

    void setComplete() {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(mutex2);
        complete = true;
    }

    bool isComplete() {
        return complete;
    }

    bool isEmpty() {
        return first==nullptr;
    }

    void push(T data) {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(mutex);

        Item *newItem = new Item();
        newItem->data = data;

        if (first == nullptr) {
            first = newItem;
            last = newItem;
        } else {
            last->next = newItem;
            newItem->prev = last;
            last = newItem;
        }
    }

    T pop() {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(mutex);

        T value = first->data;
        Item* item = first->next;
        delete first;

        if (item == nullptr) {
            first = nullptr;
            last = nullptr;
        } else {
            item->prev = nullptr;
            first = item;
        }
        return value;
    }
};

void generator(AbstractQueue<char> *q) {

    const char *s = "I want it all. I want it now!";

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        const char *p = s;
        while (*p != '\0') {
            q->push(*p);
            p++;
        }
    }

    q->setComplete();
}

void coder(AbstractQueue<char> *a, AbstractQueue<char> *b) {
    while(true) {
        if(!a->isEmpty()) {  
            char ch = a->pop();
            b->push(ch + 1);
        } else if (a->isComplete()) {            
            a->incCountThread();
            break;
        }
    }
}

int main(void) {

    while(true) {
        AbstractQueue<char> *q0 = new Queue<char>();
        AbstractQueue<char> *q1 = new Queue<char>();

        std::thread t0(generator, q0);
        std::thread t11(coder, q0, q1);
        std::thread t12(coder, q0, q1);

        t0.join();
        t11.join();
        t12.join();

        if (q0->getCountThread()==2) {
            delete q0;
            delete q1;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Дело в том, что ваши операции слишком мелкогранулярны, а некоторые из них даже не защищены мьютексом.

Посмотрите, например, на код из функции `coder`:

```
if(!a->isEmpty()) {  
    char ch = a->pop();
```

Проверка `isEmpty()` у вас закодирована вовсе без мьютекса, это значит, что у вас может быть возвращено устаревшее значение. Но это — меньшая их проблем, далеко не самая серьёзная.

Вот более серьёзная проблема: в следующее мгновение после этой проверки, перед вызовом `pop()` у вас очередь `a` уже может быть пуста! Другой поток может прийти и забрать последний элемент. И операция `pop()` провалится.

В качестве выхода, можно попробовать функцию написать `try_pop`, которая будет возвращать *два* значения: верхний элемент очереди и флаг успеха операции. В коде вы должны будете под мьютексом проверять, пустая ли очередь, и доставать из неё элемент, не отпуская мьютекс.

---

Да, и нет смысла заводить разные мьютексы для разных «частей» объекта. Используйте один общий мьютекс. И не забывайте, что любой доступ к разделяемым между потоками данным (будь то запись или чтение) должен проходить под мьютексом.

У вас в коде есть ещё несколько проблемных мест (`getCountThread`, `isComplete`), исправьте их. Если `isComplete` ещё имеет смысл, то я не вижу смысла в `getCountThread` (ведь число непосредственно после возврата результата может измениться!), так что возможно эта функция вам вовсе не нужна.